# Xcode Post Archive Action - Archive Path Environment Variable

Tags: xcode, environment-variables, xcarchive

I'm using Xcode 11.3.1 (11C504) on macOS Catalina version 10.15.2 (19C57), to create an iOS app. 

I want to add a post archive step that will run manipulation on the xcarchive files. 
I'm not sure which environment variable provide the archive path.

Thanks

Comment: it's Xcode. Please.

Comment: And please specify more details... I'd first refer to official documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/customizing_the_notarization_workflow/customizing_the_xcode_archive_process

Comment: What more details should I provide?

Comment: did you check out the link I posted above?

Comment: Yes. I also found this documentation before I asked the question. 
Still I don't understand from the documentation's example what is the environment variable that provides me with the xcarchive path.

Comment: Apparently I missed the "ARCHIVE_PATH" environment variable in the example. 
Thank @DominikBucher for your help. If you want to make it an answer from that I will accept it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `$ARCHIVE_PATH` to achieve this.

To debug your script add `exec > "/tmp/Xcode.log" 2>&1` to the beginning

You can then view output log in `/tmp/Xcode.log`

I hope this helps